# What does 打着 mean in 不能打着传统文化的旗号去否认简体字?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

In the following sentence:

> 众所周知，简体字源于历史上人们自行简化的手书体，它是以繁体字为基础的，不能**打着**传统文化的旗号去否认简体字。

打着 means "hit the mark", according to Pleco. 百度词典 does not have the entry for the word.

I struggle to understand the meaning of 打着 in this context, which likely is either one of the following:

- Unless you "hit" the flag of the traditional culture, you cannot veto the Simplified Chinese. (i.e. if you "hit" the flag, you could veto it; this is from 不能 and 否认, two negation words)
- You cannot "hit" the flag of the traditional culture to veto the Simplified Chinese. (i.e. you cannot veto the Simplified Chinese by "hitting" the flag)
- Or maybe another meaning?

I'm not sure if 打 or 打着 (is 打着 a word here or 打 + particle?) has the positive or negative connotation in this context to begin with... It is likely 比喻 in this context.

Comment: well, during cultural revolution, there was a slogan "扛著紅旗反紅旗". later, another "proverb" "唱紅打黑". anyway, the sentence quoted is, . . . clear, significant style from that area.

Comment: 打 bkrs：打 I v.
**1) generalized verb of doing with specific meaning determined by its object**  see examples
2) strike; hit
打人不对。 It's not right to hit people.
3) fight
4) construct
5) forge
6) mix

Comment: cf.  高举。。.旗帜 hold high the banner of ,,,https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/what-does-%e9%ab%98%e4%b8%be%e6%97%97%e5%b8%9c-mean

Comment: You can take 打着...旗号 as a set phrase, meaning *flaunt the banner of or under the signboard of*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up the entries for **旗号** you might get a better idea of what's going on here:

**ABC**

> 2
> DEROG.
> banner, flag
>
> 打着…的旗号
> dǎzhe ... de qíhào
> flaunt the banner of ...

**PLC**

> NOUN
> USUALLY PEJORATIVE
> banner; flag
>
> 打着……的旗号
> dǎ zhe … de qíhào
> flaunt the banner of...

So we've now learned a set pattern or phrasal structure:

**打着……的旗号**.

---

But the definition `flaunt the banner of...` doesn't do much for us, so what does it actually mean?

**Oxford** gives us an example sentence in its entry for *旗号*:

> 2
> FIGURATIVE
> pretext
>
> 打着人权的旗号干涉别国内政
> interfere in the internal affairs of other countries under the pretext of human rights

and there is our lovely succinct phrase: `under the pretext of`.

---

- 不能打着传统文化的旗号去否认简体字 = simplified characters cannot be nullified under the pretext of traditional Chinese culture.
- 打着 itself is not a word but just a combination of `hold + ing` basically.
- this whole phrasal structure is derogatory by nature, but 打着 itself is fairly neutral.
- 打着……的幌子 is another common phrase also meaning `under the pretense of`
- 打着……的招牌 is another common phrase also meaning `under the guise of`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Sometimes Pleco does not make sense and gets me confused...

Answer (score 3):

'打' in '打着旗号' means 'to display/ to hold up'

打着 means 'displaying/ holding up'

旗号 (flag/ banner) is a metaphor for 'claim; declaration'

More examples:

(打着)少林正宗的招牌 = (displaying/ holding up) signboard of authentic Shaolin

(打着)燈籠 = displaying/ holding up lantern

(打着)雨傘 = holding up umbrella

(打)手勢 = (display) gesture = to gesture

> *I'm not sure if 打 or 打着 (is 打着 a word here or 打 + particle?) has the positive or negative connotation in this context to begin with... It is likely 比喻 in this context.*

打 is the verb, 着 is a particle that indicates 'on going' status of the verb. There's no positive or negative connotation on the verb 打 (displaying/ holding up) itself

打燈籠 and 打傘 are common terms that use '打' as 'to display/ to hold up'

> "*不能打着传统文化的旗号去否认简体字*"
>
> "Should not holding up the banner of 'Traditional Culture' to dismiss simplified characters"

Side note: *"和尚打傘: 無法無天" - "Monk holding up umbrella: no law (hair) no rule (sky)*

Comment: I think the original sentence means 'ought not/should not ...' instead of 'cannot ...'.

Comment: yeah, base on the context, it is more like 'should not'

Answer (score 2):

There are 20 meaning associated with  ***[打](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/6253.htm) .***

You must read the full context to derive the exact meaning, i.e.

- 打着旗号  : carrying the flag.    打 here mean carrying， announce,

Following show examples of other context that change the meaning

- 打着鱼丸 ：Making fish ball (a delicacy)
- 打着球 ： playing ball
- 打着字 ： typing using keyboard/typewritter

Comment: also see comment #2

Comment: @user6065 the comments section is not the place for answers.

Comment: @user6065 : be descriptive.

Comment: re comment #2 to preceding answer, users note that author of comment apparently on a previous occasion expected a comment to provide answer see comment ＃５ of
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/using-xi%c3%a0nz%c3%a0i-and-zh%c3%a8ngz%c3%a0i-in-a-single-sentence

Answer (score 0):

打着。。。去 discard, ignore, disregard

众所周知，
As everyone knows
简体字源于历史上人们自行简化的手书体，
simplified (Chinese) writing, historically, had its origins in people voluntarily simplifying their writing style,
它是以繁体字为基础的，
they used traditional characters as their basis,
不能打着传统文化的旗号去
we can't ignore the traditional component (of simplified writing)
否认简体字。
deny (it is a part of) simplified (characters)

Answer (score 0):

No-one's actually said it so I'll point it out so it's clear - 打着 here is 打 plus a particle 着 (zhe)

Comment: I already pointed it out in my answer, "打 is the verb, 着 is a particle that indicates 'on going' status of the verb"